# Braintree Marketplace | How to split-up the payment after receiving it in Master Merchant account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, e-commerce, payment-gateway, braintree

I am developing a multi-vendor E-Commerce store, where a customer can purchase items from multiple stores. The customer pays only one time for the entire order, which may contain items from multiple stores (sub-merchants). As of now, entire (single) payment is made to the Master merchant account. Is there anyway to distribute this payment among multiple sub-merchants after receiving in Master merchant account?

I already know about [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/create/node). But using this, at a time, I can create a transaction for only one sub-merchant, whereas the customer pays only once for entire order (which may contain items from multiple sub-merchants).

Is there anyway to achieve the above described flow? Or any other alternative to collect payment from the customer and distribute among sub-merchants?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well!

Braintree doesn't have that feature for now. I would recommend you to check [HyperWallet](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/payouts) Solution.

Thanks.